# Formula for the covariance of logs in exponential families

Tags: variance, covariance, logarithm, exponential-family

I could not understand and don't see how the author derived equation (16). The Covariance is with respect to a pdf $\mu_k$ for the random vector $u$. The variable $\xi$ is a ratio of two densities and is equal to $ \frac{\mu_{k+1}}{\mu_k}$, both $\mu_{k+1}$ and $\mu_k$ are densities from the exponential family. The function $h_k(u,v) = \frac{\phi(u,v)}{\mu_{k+1}} = \frac{h_{k-1}}{\xi_{k}}$. And $\phi$ is some given function.

[image: Screen shot from the paper: http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/jae.3950080510]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that
\begin{array}
= Cov\left[\log(\xi), \log\left(\frac{h_k^2}{\xi}\right)\right]  \\
= Cov\left[\log(\xi) - \log(h_k) +\log(h_k), 2\log(h_k)  - \log(\xi) \right]  \\
= Cov\left[\log(\xi) - \log(h_k), \log(h_k) - \log(\xi) \right] + Cov\left[ \log(h_k), \log(h_k) \right] \\
= Var\left[\log(h_k)\right] - Var\left[ \log(h_k) - \log(\xi)  \right] 
\end{array}

So it really is just rewriting the expression.